# pip3 install teseract-ocr : failed

Tags: python, tesseract

When I try to run pip3 install teseract-ocr it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-37v3jvjx/tesseract-ocr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-j_ond470/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
ERROR: running install
running build
running build_py
file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
file tesseract_ocr.py (for module tesseract_ocr) not found
running build_ext
building 'tesseract_ocr' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c tesseract_ocr.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/tesseract_ocr.o
In file included from tesseract_ocr.cpp:636:
In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:26:
In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/apitypes.h:23:
/usr/local/include/tesseract/publictypes.h:33:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr int kPointsPerInch = 72;
^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/publictypes.h:33:11: error: expected unqualified-id
constexpr int kPointsPerInch = 72;
          ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/publictypes.h:38:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr int kMinCredibleResolution = 70;
^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/publictypes.h:38:11: error: expected unqualified-id
constexpr int kMinCredibleResolution = 70;
          ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/publictypes.h:40:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr int kMaxCredibleResolution = 2400;
^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/publictypes.h:40:11: error: expected unqualified-id
constexpr int kMaxCredibleResolution = 2400;
          ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/publictypes.h:45:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr int kResolutionEstimationFactor = 10;
^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/publictypes.h:45:11: error: expected unqualified-id
constexpr int kResolutionEstimationFactor = 10;
          ^
In file included from tesseract_ocr.cpp:636:
In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:30:
In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/resultiterator.h:27:
In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/ltrresultiterator.h:27:
/usr/local/include/tesseract/unichar.h:34:20: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using UNICHAR_ID = int;
                   ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/unichar.h:51:16: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using char32 = signed int;
               ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/unichar.h:108:16: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    using CI = const_iterator;
               ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/unichar.h:171:8: error: function definition does not declare parameters
  char chars[UNICHAR_LEN]{};
       ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/unichar.h:60:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'chars'
    memset(chars, 0, UNICHAR_LEN);
           ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/unichar.h:78:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'chars'
    int len = chars[UNICHAR_LEN - 1];
              ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/unichar.h:84:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'chars'
    return chars;
           ^
In file included from tesseract_ocr.cpp:636:
In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:30:
In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/resultiterator.h:27:
/usr/local/include/tesseract/ltrresultiterator.h:68:24: warning: 'override' keyword is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  ~LTRResultIterator() override;
                       ^
In file included from tesseract_ocr.cpp:636:
In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:30:
/usr/local/include/tesseract/resultiterator.h:49:21: warning: 'override' keyword is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  ~ResultIterator() override = default;
                    ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/resultiterator.h:49:32: warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  ~ResultIterator() override = default;
                               ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/resultiterator.h:56:16: warning: 'override' keyword is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  void Begin() override;
               ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/resultiterator.h:70:38: warning: 'override' keyword is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  bool Next(PageIteratorLevel level) override;
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/resultiterator.h:78:55: warning: 'override' keyword is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  bool IsAtBeginningOf(PageIteratorLevel level) const override;
                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/resultiterator.h:86:66: warning: 'override' keyword is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                                PageIteratorLevel element) const override;
                                                                 ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/resultiterator.h:103:63: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
  virtual std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<const char*, float>>>*
                                                              ^~
                                                              > >
In file included from tesseract_ocr.cpp:636:
In file included from /usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:31:
/usr/local/include/tesseract/serialis.h:43:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr size_t countof(T const (&)[N]) noexcept {
^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/serialis.h:43:11: warning: variable templates are a C++14 extension [-Wc++14-extensions]
constexpr size_t countof(T const (&)[N]) noexcept {
          ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/serialis.h:43:17: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
constexpr size_t countof(T const (&)[N]) noexcept {
                ^
                ;
/usr/local/include/tesseract/serialis.h:43:18: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
constexpr size_t countof(T const (&)[N]) noexcept {
                 ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/serialis.h:43:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'T'
constexpr size_t countof(T const (&)[N]) noexcept {
                         ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/serialis.h:43:41: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
constexpr size_t countof(T const (&)[N]) noexcept {
                                        ^
                                        ;
/usr/local/include/tesseract/serialis.h:52:20: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using FileWriter = bool (*)(const GenericVector<char>&, const STRING&);
                   ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/serialis.h:55:40: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
bool DeSerialize(FILE* fp, char* data, size_t n = 1);
                                       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
12 warnings and 20 errors generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-37v3jvjx/tesseract-ocr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-j_ond470/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-37v3jvjx/tesseract-ocr/
```

I have tried root and tesseract for python and homebrew is installed. Please forgive me if a question like this has been posted. Does anyone no how to solve this?

**UPDATE**
When I try it through termnal it works without a problem. But through the IDE it calls no tesseract found.

Comment: did you try other modules - `tesseract-python`, `pytesseract` ? They may need C/C++ program `tesseract` - ie. `apt install tesseract-ocr` on Linux Mint/Ubuntu

Comment: maybe you find precompiled C/C++ program on https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki and after this install python wrapper - `tesseract-python`, `pytesseract`

Comment: I am using pytesseract but it requires tesseract. I have tesseract installed but it says tesseract not found and I found tutorials that said I have to run: `pip3 install tesseract`, and `pip3 install tesseract-ocr`

Comment: I have also installed `pytesseract` (using `pip`) and `tesseract` I installed precompiled probaly from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki or using `apt` on Linux but I don't remeber problems with compiling. But if you try to install `teseract-ocr` from `pip`  then maybe it use C/C++ code and compile it.